# Is there a command to turn several po files into a multilingual list?

Tags: converters, gettext

We use a custom translation format in our opensource project
It looks like this

> ```
> en:Fish menus for babies 
> fr:Menus Poissons pour bébé 
> nl:Baby-vismaaltijden
> ```

I was wondering if there was some translation format that looks like this, and thus if there's a command line tool that would enable two-way migration to GetText (.po files, one per language).

Comment: any multilingual list-like format would do